# Approximation of pseudogeometric progression

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, approximation-theory

Let $f_n(x)=1+x+x^{\sqrt{2}}+x^{\sqrt{3}}+x^{\sqrt{4}}+\cdots+x^{\sqrt{n}}$ be a sequence of functions on the interval $[0, 1]$. Is there a good closed form approximation for such a function ( whatever "good" means), analogous to the well-known expression for the sum of geometric progression.

Such an approximation is needed to get an asymptotics on the positive root of equation $f_n(x)=\ln(n)$ for large $n$.

Comment: If you type `x^{\sqrt 4}+...+x^{\sqrt n}` in genuine $\LaTeX$ (as opposed to MathJax, which is used here), then you will see $x^{\sqrt 4}+\text{...}+x^{\sqrt n}$ rather than $x^{\sqrt 4}+\cdots+x^{\sqrt n}$ or $x^{\sqrt 4}+\ldots+x^{\sqrt n}.$ And even in MathJax, notice that there is a conspicuous difference between $x^{\sqrt 4}+...+x^{\sqrt n}$ and $x^{\sqrt 4}+\ldots+x^{\sqrt n}:$ the dots are not horizontally centered. I wonder why so few mathematicians understand the reason why Donald Knuth created TeX.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For natural $n$ and $x\in(0,1)$, one has
$$L_n(x)\le f_n(x)\le U_n(x), \tag{10}\label{10}$$
where
$$U_n(x):=1+I_n(x), \tag{20}\label{20}$$
$$I_n(x):=\int_0^n x^{\sqrt t}\,dt
=2\frac{1+x^{\sqrt{n}} \left(\sqrt{n} \ln x-1\right)}{\ln^2 x},$$
$$L_n(x):=I_{n+1}(x). \tag{30}\label{30}$$

Next, fixing any real $c>0$ and letting $n\to\infty$, for $x=1-c/\sqrt{\ln n}$ we will have
$$\sqrt n\ln x
\sim-c\sqrt{n/\ln n}\to-\infty, $$
$$x^{\sqrt{n}}=\exp(\sqrt n\ln x)=\exp(-(c+o(1))\sqrt{n/\ln n}),$$
and hence
$$I_n(1-c/\sqrt{\ln n})\sim\frac2{c^2}\,\ln n.$$
Similarly (or because $1-c/\sqrt{\ln(n+1)}=1-(c+o(1))/\sqrt{\ln n}\;$), we have
$$I_{n+1}(1-c/\sqrt{\ln n})\sim\frac2{c^2}\,\ln n.$$

So, by \eqref{20} and \eqref{30},
$$U_n(1-c/\sqrt{\ln n})\sim\frac2{c^2}\,\ln n\sim L_n(1-c/\sqrt{\ln n}).$$
Hence, in view of \eqref{10},
$$f_n(1-c/\sqrt{\ln n})\sim\frac2{c^2}\,\ln n.$$

So, for the only zero $x=x_n$ of the strictly increasing function $(0,1)\ni u\mapsto f_n(u)-\ln n$ we have
$$x_n=1-\sqrt{\frac{2+o(1)}{\ln n}}$$
as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is very helpful asymptotics of the equation root! You actually saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 6):

The first few term of the [Euler-MacLaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) give a reasonably accurate closed-form approximation:
The plots below compare
$$f_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n x^{\sqrt{k}}$$
(blue curve) with
$$g_n(x)=\tfrac{1}{2}(x^{\sqrt{n}}+1)+\int_0^n x^{\sqrt t}\,dt$$
$$\qquad=\tfrac{1}{2} \left(x^{\sqrt{n}}+1\right)+\frac{2 x^{\sqrt{n}} \left(\sqrt{n} \ln x-1\right)+2}{\ln ^2 x},$$
(gold curve), for $n=20$ and $n=40$:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

In my former research group, in the area of statistical thermodynmics, we had to solve for $x$ a more general equation
$$\sum_{k=0}^n x^{k^\alpha}=a\,\log(n)$$ Adapted to your problem, using Euler-MacLaurin summation, we have
$$f_n(x)\sim g_n(x)=\frac{x^{\sqrt{n}} \left(4 \sqrt{n} \log (x)+\log ^2(x)-4\right)}{2 \log
   ^2(x)}+1+\frac x 2-$$ $$\frac{2 x (\log (x)-1)}{\log ^2(x)}-
x\log(x)\sum_{p=0}^4 b_p \, \log^p(x) $$ the $b_p$ coefficients being
$$\left\{\frac{1901}{46080},\frac{19}{46080},-\frac{41}{322560},-\frac{1}{9
   6768},\frac{1}{967680}\right\}$$

Solving
$$g_n(x)=\log(n)$$ does not make any difficulty  using Newton-like methods and, for your problem,  our simple starting point becomes
$$x_0=\left(1+\frac{\log (2)}{8}\right)\exp \left(-\frac{1+\log (2)}{\sqrt{\log (n)}}\right)$$ Typically, a couple of Newton iterations would be sufficient.

In the table below, I give, for a few values of $n$, the estimate, the solution of the approximate form of the equation as well as the exact solution.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
n & \text{estimate} & \text{approximate solution} & \text{exact solution} \\
 10 & 0.356042 &  0.362166 &  0.362256 \\
 20 & 0.408550 &  0.414665 &  0.414683 \\
 30 & 0.433882 &  0.437365 &  0.437373 \\
 40 & 0.450023 &  0.451915 &  0.451919 \\
 50 & 0.461651 &  0.462610 &  0.462612 \\
 60 & 0.470636 &  0.471033 &  0.471035 \\
 70 & 0.477902 &  0.477952 &  0.477954 \\
 80 & 0.483968 &  0.483800 &  0.483801 \\
  90 & 0.489153 &  0.488847 &  0.488848 \\
 100 & 0.493665 &  0.493273 &  0.493274 \\
 200 & 0.520753 &  0.520240 &  0.520241 \\
 300 & 0.534805 &  0.534276 &  0.534276 \\
 400 & 0.544100 &  0.543495 &  0.543496 \\
 500 & 0.550961 &  0.550254 &  0.550255 \\
 600 & 0.556359 &  0.555541 &  0.555541 \\
 700 & 0.560784 &  0.559854 &  0.559855 \\
 800 & 0.564520 &  0.563481 &  0.563482 \\
  900 & 0.567744 &  0.566600 &  0.566601 \\
 1000 & 0.570573 &  0.569329 &  0.569329 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Let

$$a=1+\frac{\log (2)}{8} \qquad \qquad b=1+\log (2)$$ Asymptotically
$$g_n(x_0)-\log(n)=2 \sqrt n \frac{\left(a e^{-\frac{b}{\sqrt{\log
   (n)}}}\right)^{\sqrt{n}}}{\log \left(a e^{-\frac{b}{\sqrt{\log
   (n)}}}\right)}$$ which is very small (for $n=100$, it is $-1.22\times 10^{-3}$ and for $n=10000$ it is $-5.05\times 10^{-21}$).

Comment: Thank you for such a useful comment. Actually I am very curious now, how this kind of equation appeared in statistical thermodynamics. Can you give brief explanation and may be a link to the work? Because in my case this equation is related to dimension reduction  in data science, the area seemingly quite far away from thermodynamics...

Comment: @DmitriScheglov. This was nt a comment but an answer (joke). We did not publish the work and, as for as I know, the company I was working for does not want to release information since this cam when building a thermodynamic model for systems of polymers (in the Gibbs ensemble). Be sure that before answering I asked if I could give this result which is very simple. If fact, I am still working this specific case which is very interesting. If I find anything of interest, I shall post it.Cheers :-)